# Josephus Problem - Is there a position with 0 chance of surviving, regardless of any skip interval?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof, josephus

Consider a variant of [Josephus Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem). Instead of finding the initial position `p_survive` of the survivor, I want vary the skip interval `k` and determine if the following is true:

> For all positions `p` in the circle, there exists a value of `k` such that `p = p_survive` exists.

Intuitively, it seems like the statement is true because the circle changes in size after each elimination while the skip interval remains constant, so there is a chance for each position to be the surviving position after using *many* values of `k`. However, I am not sure if there is a more robust proof (or disproof) for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This feels to me like it might be more on topic for (and get better answers in) https://cs.stackexchange.com or https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Oh, I see. Alright I'll head over to those sites, thanks!

Comment: No worries! I could be wrong, and you might get good answers over here, but in general I've seen more practical or programming-related questions on this site.  As presented, this question seems very theoretical and without a specific stated application, so I'm guessing you'll have better luck at one of those other sites.

Comment: After trying to post on math.stackexchange.com, found a [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143380/inverse-josephus-problem), that kind of answers my question. Should've dug deeper, oops! Thanks @M.Justin for pointing me towards those 2 sites!